# Zombie Connection in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

def add_person(name):
    s = DBSession()
    s.add(Person(name=name))
    s.commit()
```

Everytime I run add_person() another connection is created with my postgreSQL DB.
Looking at:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

I see the count going up, until I get a `Remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections` error.

How do I kill those connections? Am I wrong in opening a new session everytime I want to add a Person record?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should keep your `Session` object (here `DBSession`) [separate from any functions that make changes to the database](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it). So in your case you might try something like this instead:

```
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
session = DBSession()  # create your session outside of functions that will modify database

def add_person(name):
    session.add(Person(name=name))
    session.commit()
```

Now you will not get new connections every time you add a person to the database.